# EXC_BAD_ACCESS after converting HTTP response to string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have the following code, from which I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(responseString);
}
```

The weird thing is, the bad access error is actually coming from the `NSLog()` line, when it tries to access `responseString`. I've even tried adding a `retain` or `autorelease` to the first line, but I still get the error.

Any thoughts on what might be happening? To my knowledge, there shouldn't be any issue, because I'm calling it immediately after it's defined, so `responseString` should not have been released yet, correct?

EDIT: I should mention, `receivedData` is an `NSMutableData` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
```

Your `responseString` might have some 'reserved sequences', like `%@` or `%d`.
The former will cause `NSLog` to access 'object' in arbitrary location in memory, since it doesn't know (or doesn't care) how many parameters you actually provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try `NSLog (@"%@", responseString);`