# Cleaning up NSString variable created from HTTP response

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, http

I have a JSON response which I convert to an NSDictionary that looks like this

```
 response {
    cid = 30;
    female =     {
        id = 24;
        "img_url" = "/static/images/upload/24";
    };
    male =     {
        id = 26;
        "img_url" = "/static/images/upload/26";
    };
}
```

I then extract the cid code by plugging it into a NSString variable like this:

```
cid = [response objectForKey:@"cid"];
```

Later in an another method I try to use cid in an ASIFormDataRequest

```
[request setPostValue:cid forKey:@"cid"];
```

but that crashes the programme. If I place `cid = @"7"` (for example) right before this setPostValue:cid statement everything works fine, so I know the functionality of the request is fine. Likewise if I `NSLog(@"%@",cid);` that also works.

I believe my question is [identical to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995334/exc-bad-access-after-converting-http-response-to-string), but no one has given a concrete answer as to how to solve it.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

There is not crash log. Xcode just gives me this message in the bottom bar:

[image]

** EDIT 2 **

Here are some images from me printing with the debugger. I don't know if I've done this correctly though.

[image]

Here is how I'm plugging in response data into CID. CID is an NSString declared in the header file with the whole @property(nonatomic, retain) bit.

[image]

**EDIT 3**

Also if I print

```
NSLog(@"%@", cid);
```

right before posting the cid value, I get EXC_BAC ACCESS error

Comment: try to escape that `cid` variable value

Comment: Please paste the exact crash. I'm wondering at this point if it's because your `cid` variable is an `NSNumber` but `-setPostValue:forKey:` wants an `NSString` instead.

Comment: @Marek Sebera, how do I do that?

Comment: @Kevin Ballard. Please see my first edit.

Comment: Eric, can you paste a little bit more of the code, including the variable definitions?  In addition, my recommendation to you would be to run this in the debugger and set a breakpoint on the line that crashes.  When you hit that breakpoint, please edit your question to include the type of cid and the value, as presented in the debugger.  The next interesting thing to know is if the application crashes in the debugger when you step over that line.

Comment: @Eric: If you're attached with the debugger, then yes it will break into GDB instead of producing a crash log. Try running without the debugger, that will get you a crash log. Or check the backtrace in Xcode; it's possible it threw an exception that triggered the break into GDB and Xcode is only showing the stack frame with symbols (e.g. your code). It's also possible it crashed outright, but again it will only be showing your code. The backtrace will have more information.

Comment: @Kevin I'm trying to run without attaching to the debugger, but can't seem to see how to do that. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> CID is an NSString declared in the header file with the whole @property(nonatomic, retain) bit.

Even though you’ve declared it as a retain property, you’re not using it as a property. By using:

```
cid = [number stringValue];
```

you’re directly assigning an object to `cid`, which is the backing instance variable, thus bypassing the property setter that would retain that object. This means that as soon as the corresponding autorelease pool is drained, `cid` probably no longer points to a valid object.

When you’re interested in an object that should survive autorelease pool drains then you should take ownership of it. With retain properties, this means invoking the property setter, e.g.:

```
self.cid = [number stringValue];
```

This will retain the `[number stringValue]` assigned to the `cid` property and, if everything else in your program is correct with regard to memory management, you’ll be able to use `self.cid` in other parts of your program, as in:

> Later in an another method I try to use cid in an ASIFormDataRequest

For the record, `NSString` properties are usually copy instead of retain to prevent side effects when the property is assigned a mutable string.

Answer (score -1):

When you take cid like this cid = [response objectForKey:@"cid"]; then it returns an autorelease object. It would be released when method returns. So try using alloc.

`if(cid != nil)

[cid release];

cid = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[response objectForKey:@"cid"]];`

and then

`[request setPostValue:cid forKey:@"cid"];`

If this don't solve your problem then post here.

Comment: Absolutely terrible answer. Every single thing is wrong. First, the test for `cid != nil` is utterly useless before `[cid release]`, because the message-to-nil behavior makes `[cid release]` safe regardless of cid is nil. Second, using `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:foo]` is absolutely wrong. If `[response objectForKey:@"cid"]` is a string already, then it's useless. If it's not, you just passed a non-string to `-initWithString:` and will almost certainly crash. Third, you've now made `cid` contain either an autoreleased or a retained object, which is absolutely wrong.

Comment: all I want to convey is that...an autorelease object returned by other method will not be available in other method.

Comment: Oh I also forgot, the entire premise of `[cid release]` is flawed, because `cid` is an autoreleased object and the `[cid release]` *will* cause a crash.